# Livewire component unintentionally gets nested inside another

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

My Laravel app has a blade view that contains two Livewire component that I want to put inside a grid.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-12">
  <div class="col-span-8">
    <livewire:cars.index />
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-4">
     <livewire:types.index />
  </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason the second Livewire component gets nested inside the first one. Am I breaking some convention? Each component has one root element.

Comment: can you show your  <livewire:cars.index />?

Answer (score 0):

Check if
`<livewire:cars.index />`
component doesnt have any `div` that isnt closed